# Apache HTTP Proxy - Chunked to Unchunked?

Tags: apache, nginx, proxy, chunked

I have access to a 3rd party Web API that only responds with chunked response data (Transfer-Encoding: Chunked).

On the other side I have a 3rd party client that can only accept unchunked responses (Content-Length: x).  The client is configurable, so I can change the API endpoint.

Is it possible to setup Apache httpd to "unchunk" the response data, remove the "chunked" header and apply the correct "content-length"?

I have tried nginx (windows) and that just passes the unchunked data through.  I have also tried Apache with mod_proxy but that seems to pass the chunked data through too.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean the API is configurable? If so, you're likely not setting the content-length header, and due to the HTTP 1.1 spec which says that all clients MUST support chunked transfer encoding, you're mostly out of luck.

Comment: No, sadly, only the client is configurable. The client is NetSuite. NetSuite provides a wrapper around XMLhttprequest but does not handle chunked responses. I can change the endpoint (ie: run the request through a proxy) but that's all I can change. The final endpoint is 3rd party so I can't turn chunking off at that end. That's why I was hoping I could find a proxy to do the conversion from chunked to unchunked for me.